# Midrule Not Working

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, booktabs

Does anyone know why this isn't working? I'm trying to add horizontal lines to my graphs, and it's breaking at the `\midrule` command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    ColA, ColB, ColC
    0.17, 0.91, 0.67
    0.15, 0.17, 0.92
    0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}

\def\buildTable#1{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{#1}\rawdata%
    \xdef\theTable{\noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[every row/.style={before row=\midrule}]}%
    \theTable{\rawdata}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \buildTable
    {%CSV file
        test.csv%
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: need `tabular` environment?

Comment: @AML `\pgfplotstabletypeset` makes one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want `\midrule`s before every row use simply the `before row` key

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    ColA, ColB, ColC
    0.17, 0.91, 0.67
    0.15, 0.17, 0.92
    0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}

\def\buildTable#1{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{#1}\rawdata%
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[before row= \midrule]\rawdata
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \buildTable
    {%CSV file
        test.csv%
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I do not know, why the code makes a detour via `\xdef` and `\TheTable`. But, I would use `\noexpand` before `\midrule` inside the `\xdef`.

Also, I have not found the style `every row` in the documentation, but `every head row` exists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    ColA, ColB, ColC
    0.17, 0.91, 0.67
    0.15, 0.17, 0.92
    0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\buildTable}[1]{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{#1}\rawdata
    \xdef\theTable{%
        \noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[
            every head row/.style={after row=\noexpand\midrule}%
        ]}%
    \theTable{\rawdata}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \buildTable
    {%CSV file
        test.csv%
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With alignment at the decimal separator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    ColA, ColB, ColC
    0.17, 0.91, 0.67
    0.15, 0.17, 0.92
    0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\buildTable}[1]{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{#1}\rawdata
    \xdef\theTable{%
        \noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[
            dec sep align={c},
            every head row/.style={after row=\noexpand\midrule}%
        ]}%
    \theTable{\rawdata}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \buildTable
    {%CSV file
        test.csv%
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]